# Two ifs and one else in C#. What happens?

Tags: c#, if-statement

for example:

```
if(cond1)
if(cond2) DoCond2();
else DoCond3();
```

Will the `else` statement be considered as the else of the first `if` or the second `if`? Why? (is there an explanation from syntactic point of view?)
Is the answer also the same in the other C-based programming languages such as C and Java?

Note: this is not homework. I can easily test it, and use the curly brackets if I don't like the default behaviour, but I'm curious as to the reason.

**Edit** Guys, apparently there was a very serious mistake in the original example. Please check again. I know, it's embarrassing. Sorry.

Comment: You can test this out for yourself online: http://codepad.org/, http://compilr.com/

Comment: FYI: This is also known as the [dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else) problem.

Comment: Always add braces then you'll never be left wondering.

Comment: This is definitely one of those constructions I slap curlies around to enforce readability even if I know the convention.

Comment: That's why I love Python - there's no ambiguity with forced-indents!

Comment: Did you find any of these answers useful ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

In nested if statements, the else clause belongs to the last if that does not have a corresponding else.

Also C and C++, conditions can be evaluated where a result of 0 is false and any other number is true. In C#, the condition must evaluate to a boolean value true/false

**EDIT**
As per the Edit its a nested if, so the inner one is evaluated when true and still the else is with the inner if

Answer (score 2):

> Will the else statement be considered as the else of the first if or the second if?

**Edit (removed what I original said here - it doesn't apply):**

With such a construction, I couldn't tell you.  The syntax for each language is ambiguous.

But I'd personally guess it would "stick" to the closest `if`.  Otherwise it would be nearly impossible for someone to read.

I'd say try it and see, but the best solution is to apply a coding standard that forbids people from ever doing this...

> Why? (is there an explanation from syntactic point of view?)

You can check out the (often unofficial) grammar definition for each language to see why such statements hang together the way they do.

The (old) official C# grammar:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645596(v=VS.71).aspx

**Edit:** But it won't help you much, because the grammar for C-like languages in this case requires context, or deliberate work-arounds.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else#Context_Free_Solutions

> Is the answer also the same in the other C-based programming languages such as C and Java?

Grammars are complicated things, and getting nested scopes right is a bit hard.  But in general, the answer will often revolve around definitions of `block`s vs `statement`s.

You could define a `statement` as a line ended by a `;`.  Then define a `block` as a series of `statement`s surrounded by `{` `}`.

So, you could define your `if` statement as `if block-or-statement [else block-or-statement]`, the `[` `]` denoting that it is optional.

**Edit:**  The problem with this definition is that such a grammar requires context, and only solves the problem with the *original* formulation of your question.  When it is truly ambiguous (as your new, edited version), you must have higher level processing (context) to deal with the ambiguity.

C++, for example:

- (grabbed link from) [Is there a yacc-able C++ grammar?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/compiler-dependencies.html#faq-38.11)
- http://www.computing.surrey.ac.uk/research/dsrg/fog/CxxGrammar.y

A few times in that last document you will see "[dangling else](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_else)".  This specifically describes what you're looking for.

This problem exists in many languages, not just C-likes.  It is one reason you see explicit statements like `end if` in [BASIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BASIC) variants, or [Python](http://www.python.org/)'s rules for `if`s.

Comment: Yeah, really sorry about that. Just realised my mistake after reading the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to understand this it would be useful to add braces:

```
if(cond1) {
    DoCond1();
}
if(cond2) {
    DoCond2();
} else {
    DoCond3();
}
```

If there are no braces after `if` or `else`, only the first statement (in this case `DoCondX`) belongs to the if/else block.

*EDIT* Looking at the code after the edit:

```
if(cond1) {
    if(cond2) {
        DoCond2();
    } else {
        DoCond3();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding brackets definitely clarifies the results.  The brackets here do the same exact thing as the original code.

Comment: Adding braces is what I always did (and sometimes still do) when some piece of code was not clear :)

Comment: @Louis Rhys: updated the example according to your changed code

Answer (score 1):

Let's clarify how the `if` statement works.

After an `if` clause, you can have two things:

- Single line statement
- Multi line statement

The single line statement is like the two examples you provided. In that scenario, the `else` belongs to the `if` only if it is directly after it (like your second example).

The multi line statement will have curly brackets `{ }` following the if statement. An `else` following the closing bracket makes it belong to that statement.

You can "chain" `if` statements using the `else if` syntax. The following if will behave like a normal if, but it will be checked only if the previous `if` returns false. In your example, both `if` statements will be checked regardeless of the result.

Comment: technically, the `else` is "directly after" both `if`s, because the two ifs at at the same point.

Comment: No. As I wrote, a single line statement is "single line", meaning that after the first semicolon, the statement is finished, unless it's directly followed by a else. In your case, it's followed by another if.

Comment: Oops. Sorry apparantly I made a serious mistake in the example. Changed it to show what I mean. I'm pretty embarrassed

Comment: After your editing, the scenario is a bit different, but the else still remains on the second if, because it's the "closest" in declaration. If you put a second else after that, then that will belong to the outer if.